# How to check which employees came to work but did not work on 1-1-2015

Tags: sql

```
Exit_datetime       Entry_datetime      Emp_id
01/01/2015 19:15:00 01/01/2015 08:10:00 1
01/01/2015 18:15:00 01/01/2015 07:10:00 2
02/01/2015 17:15:00 02/01/2015 07:10:00 3
02/01/2015 17:15:00 02/01/2015 07:10:00 1
```

Comment: Your question needs more clarification.  What do you mean "came to work but didn't not work".  How do we know whether or not someone worked based on the data you provided?

Comment: Is there an Employee table, as you'd need to know who works there to determine whether they came to work.

Comment: I'm expecting to receive row number 3  - that show emp 3 that didn't work at 1-1-2015 and work at 2-1-2015

Answer (score 0):

I got your question.

First select `emp_id` of employees who works on 01/01/2015 and then select all employees expect previously selected employees.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table_name' WHERE emp_id NOT in (SELECT emp_id FROM `your_table_name` WHERE Entry_datetime =  '01/01/2015' OR Exit_datetime = '01/01/2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you what you want:

```
SELECT Emp_id, 
  (SELECT MAX(1) FROM emplog WHERE Emp_id=a.Emp_id 
   AND Exit_datetime>'1/1/2015' AND Entry_datetime<'1/2/2015')  worked_on_1_Jan
FROM ( SELECT Emp_id FROM emplog GROUP BY Emp_id ) a
```

You can find a little demo here: https://rextester.com/CUS26590

I extended OP's test data a little to include cases where the employee (4) started on the day before and and finished on the day after. And also a case (emp_id=1) where the multiple time spans were logged:

```
INSERT INTO emplog VALUES
('01/01/2015 11:15:00','01/01/2015 08:10:00', 1),
('01/01/2015 19:15:00','01/01/2015 12:10:00', 1),
('01/01/2015 18:15:00','01/01/2015 07:10:00', 2),
('01/02/2015 17:15:00','01/02/2015 07:10:00', 3),
('01/02/2015 17:15:00','01/02/2015 07:10:00', 1),
('01/02/2015 00:03:50','12/31/2014 23:15:00', 4),
('01/02/2015 05:10:00','01/01/2015 22:15:00', 5);

-- results:

Emp_id  worked_on_1_Jan
-----------------------
    1   1
    2   1
    3   NULL
    4   1
    5   1
```